# Custom timeout message in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I need to set a custom message for the user when Retrofit reaches the timeout. I've searched through stackoverflow and couldn't find a solution for this. I've also searched through github and found this (probably the line that's responsible for the message I'm seeing at this point):

```
ConnectException ce = new ConnectException("Failed to connect to " + route.socketAddress());
```

This is in the class `okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection.java`

So I went to that class, and since it belongs to `OkHttp` lib, it wouldn't let me edit this message.

Does anyone have any idea how I could use my own custom timeout handler?

Relevant `build.gradle` entries:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

#### EDIT:

Both solutions given below would *kind-of* work probably, but it's really ugly and I'd have to actually change the `onFailure` method in about 70-80 places which is less than ideal.

Comment: can you not check  the exception type and  check if its a instance of SocketTimeoutException and then update ui or show toast?

Comment: I could do that. Probably in `onFailure`. I thought there might be a nicer way than to use `instanceof SocketException`.

Comment: @Raghunandan The problem with this approach is that I'd have to go and change each and every `onFailure` in my project. And there's about 70-80 of them for sure. that's why I was looking for a neater solution, like configuring it somehow with a Builder.

Answer (score 1):

On failure block of retrofit network call.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
    if (t.toString().contains("SocketTimeoutException")) {
            // set your custom message here
            //view.showToast(R.string.poor_internet_connection);
    } else {
          .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error callback method use below code

```
@Override
public void error(Throwable exception) {
     String errorMsg
     if (exception instanceof java.net.SocketException || exception instanceof java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {
        errorMsg = "Your custom message here"
    }
}
```